# Using awk in a file that has forward slashes in it

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file containing lines similar too ...

```
/home/test/gp/fish/lib/fish.eye
/home/test/gp/fish/kerf/pl/teeth.eye
```

I want to take the last string at the end of each line and put it at the start of the line, for example ..

```
cp fish.eye /home/test/gp/fish/lib/fish.eye
cp teeth.eye /home/test/gp/fish/kerf/pl/teeth.eye
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use this for example:

```
$ awk -F/ '{print "cp", $NF, $0}' your_file
cp fish.eye /home/test/gp/fish/lib/fish.eye
cp teeth.eye /home/test/gp/fish/kerf/pl/teeth.eye
```

It sets `/` as field separator, so that the filename is the last field. Then it is a matter of printing accordingly.

Or safer, to handle filenames with spaces and globbing chars, etc ([thanks Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208008/using-awk-in-a-file-that-has-forward-slashes-in-it/24208046?noredirect=1#comment37377899_24208046)!):

```
awk -F/ '{printf "cp \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", $NF, $0}' your_file
```

---

In bash you can loop through the lines and make use of `basename`:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "cp" "$(basename "$line")" "$line"
    #printf "cp %s %s\n" "$(basename "$line")" "$line" <-- this also works
done < your_file
```

`basename` returns the strip and suffix from filenames, so that from a name like `/path/like/this.sh` you get `this.sh`.

Comment: +1 for the awk approach but make it `printf "cp \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", $NF, $0` so it'll work for file names containing spaces, globbing chars, etc. The bash one has some bugs in it and any time you write a shell loop to parse a text file it's the wrong approach anyway so so I wouldn't use that.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton :) Updated accordingly. And yes, I remember you telling me another time about not looping through files, couldn't help doing it now to use `basename`!

Comment: Any time you use `read` in shell you need to write it as `while IFS= read -r line` UNLESS you have some very specific behavior you're trying to get out of not setting `IFS=` or using `-r` and are fully aware of the caveats and side-effects. Not setting `IFS=` causes word splitting to be enabled so then it messes with white space (e.g. deletes leading and trailing blanks) and not using `-r` tells `read` to interpret escape chars so then `\t` in the input, for example, would become a literal tab character in the variable which would produce a very different output from the input.

Answer (score 3):

And the one through GNU `sed`,

```
$ sed -r 's/^.*\/(.*)$/cp \1 &/' file
cp fish.eye /home/test/gp/fish/lib/fish.eye
cp teeth.eye /home/test/gp/fish/kerf/pl/teeth.eye
```

Text after last `/` symbol are fetched and stored  into a group. Again in the replacement part, "cp group wholeline" helps to give the above output.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` [parameter substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "cp ${line##*/} $line" 
done < file
cp fish.eye /home/test/gp/fish/lib/fish.eye
cp teeth.eye /home/test/gp/fish/kerf/pl/teeth.eye
```

From the link:

```
${parameter##word} 

The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion 
(see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value 
of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter 
with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern 
(the ‘##’ case) deleted.
```

Answer (score 2):

these three sed one-liners should work too, but awk would be more straightforward:

```
sed 's/.*/& &/;s#[^ ]*/#cp #' file
```

and

```
sed 'h;s#.*/#cp #;G;s/\n/ /' file
```

and

```
sed 's#.*/\(.*\)#cp \1 &#' file
```